# pd.Series.argsort() and nan-values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use [`argsort()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) on my pandas Series and achieve the same result as [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) does.

```py
x = pd.Series([10.,40.,None,20.,None,30.])


y = x.sort_values()
# Output of y
# 0    10.0
# 3    20.0
# 5    30.0
# 1    40.0
# 2    NaN
# 4    NaN
# dtype: float64

idx = x.argsort()
# Output of idx
# 0    0
# 1    2
# 2   -1
# 3    3
# 4   -1
# 5    1
# dtype: int64

# How could f look like such that y.equals(z)==True
z = f(x,idx)
```

How to use `idx` to achieve the same result as with `sort_values()`? Or put differently: How to apply the output of `argsort()` on other sequences? In particular, the NaN or `None` entries should go to the back of the series/list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the special treatment of `NaN`s is so deep in the `pd.Series.argsort` that you should somehow treat them separately:

```py
pd.concat([x.dropna().iloc[x.dropna().argsort()], x.loc[x.isna()]])
```

Comment: This so far is the most generic answer that works for dtypes other than numbers (float, int)

Answer (score 3):

I feel like there is something off with `pandas` `argsort` and `numpy` `argsort`, for the quick fix , using `np.argsort`

```
x.iloc[np.argsort(x.values)]
Out[219]: 
0    10.0
3    20.0
5    30.0
1    40.0
2     NaN
4     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! This works as long as `x.dtype` is numeric.